# How do I plot a linear regression line in a specified bin in a histogram?

Tags: r, histogram, linear-regression

So we are trying to determine speciation rate as a function of animal weight. Animal weight follows a gaussian distribution when they are plotted altogether; hence, we only want to fit the regression line in the decreasing trend of the histogram. Specifically, the line should start from x = 2.1 and y = 3.0. Fig. 1 is my current plot using the code below, while Fig. 2 is the outcome I would like to acquire (superimposed line via paint), which I don't know how to do. Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Attached is my code:

```
    x.log = c(-2.9, -2.7, -2.5, -2.3, -2.1, -1.9, -1.7, -1.5, -1.3, -1.1, 
           -0.9,-0.7, -0.5, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1, 
            1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7, 2.9, 3.1, 3.3, 3.5, 3.7, 
            3.9, 4.1, 4.3, 4.5, 4.7, 4.9, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 5.7, 5.9, 6.1, 
            6.3, 6.5,6.9, 7.1, 7.3, 7.5, 7.7, 7.9)
    y.log = c(0, 0, 0, 0.47, 0.60, 0.95, 1.14, 1.38, 1.68, 1.79, 2.10, 2.26,
              2.29, 2.39, 2.48, 2.52, 2.79, 2.68, 2.80, 2.84, 2.96, 2.92, 
              2.91, 3.01, 2.95, 3.05, 2.94, 2.96, 2.98, 2.83, 2.85, 2.83, 
              2.71, 2.63, 2.61, 2.57, 2.37, 2.26, 2.17, 1.99, 1.87, 1.74, 
              1.62, 1.36, 1.30, 1.07, 1.20, 0.90, 0.30, 0.69, 0.30, 0.47, 0
               0.30, 0)

     # plot the histogram
     names(log.nspecies) = logbio
     log.nspecies = log.nspecies[order (as.numeric(names(log.nspecies)))]
     xpos = barplot(log.nspecies, las = 2, space = 0, col = 'red', 
           xlab = 'ln Weight', ylab = 'ln Number of species')
```

[image]
[image]